# Iterator design pattern using unique_ptr instead of raw ptr

Tags: c++, design-patterns, iterator, unique-ptr

I've got this fairly simple C++ code from refactoring.guru. It compiles and works as expected. However, it uses `new` and `delete` via the `CreateIterator()` member function, and I'd like to port it to use `unique_ptr`, but I'm not sure how to do that exactly.

I've created a `CreateIterator2()` function using `unique_ptr`, which compiles (I think this is what I want), but not if I invoke it, so I commented out the invocation.

I'm not sure what I am missing to return a smart pointer and avoid using raw `new`/`delete`.

```
// refactoring.guru c++ design patterns
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<typename T, typename U>
class Iterator {
public:
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator iter_type;

    Iterator(U* p_data, bool reverse = false) : m_p_data_(p_data) {
        m_it_ = m_p_data_->m_data_.begin();
    }

    void First() {
        m_it_ = m_p_data_->m_data_.begin();
    }

    void Next() {
        m_it_++;
    }

    bool IsDone() {
        return (m_it_ == m_p_data_->m_data_.end());
    }

    iter_type Current() {
        return m_it_;
    }

private:
    U* m_p_data_;
    iter_type m_it_;
};

template<class T>
class Container {
    friend class Iterator<T, Container>;

public:
    void Add(T a) {
        m_data_.push_back(a);
    }

    Iterator<T, Container>* CreateIterator() {
        // want to avoid this
        return new Iterator<T, Container>(this);
    }

    //think this is what I want  - compiles
    std::unique_ptr<Iterator<T, Container>> CreateIterator2() {
        return std::unique_ptr<Iterator<T, Container>>(this);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> m_data_;
};

class Data {
public:
    Data(int a = 0) : m_data_(a) {}

    void set_data(int a) {
        m_data_ = a;
    }

    int data() {
        return m_data_;
}

private:
    int m_data_;
};

void ClientCode() {
    std::cout << "________________Iterator with int______________________________________" <<        std::endl;
    Container<int> cont;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cont.Add(i);
    }

    Iterator<int, Container<int>>* it = cont.CreateIterator();
    for (it->First(); !it->IsDone(); it->Next()) {
        std::cout << *it->Current() << std::endl;
    }

    //THIS DOESN"T COMPILE
    //std::unique_ptr<Iterator<int, Container<int>> it = cont.CreateIterator2();
    //for (it->First(); !it->IsDone(); it->Next()) {
    //    std::cout << *it->Current() << std::endl;
    //}


    Container<Data> cont2;
    Data a(100), b(1000), c(10000);
    cont2.Add(a);
    cont2.Add(b);
    cont2.Add(c);

    std::cout << "________________Iterator with custom Class______________________________" << std::endl;
    Iterator<Data, Container<Data>>* it2 = cont2.CreateIterator();
    for (it2->First(); !it2->IsDone(); it2->Next()) {
    std::cout << it2->Current()->data() << std::endl;
    }
    //avoid this
    delete it;
    delete it2;
}

int main() {
    ClientCode();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a pointer at all?  Can't you just return, well, an iterator from `CreateIterator`?

Comment: I'm open to best practice suggestions. Was just looking at this as an exercise to learn smart pointers. Still learning some of the ins and outs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `std::unique_ptr` simply wraps a `new`'ed object, and its destructor will call `delete` on that object.

So, this statement:

`return std::unique_ptr<Iterator<T, Container>>(this);`

is just plain wrong, as `this` is not a `new`'d object that `unique_ptr` can take ownership of. This statement is NOT equivalent to the original statement:

`return new Iterator<T, Container>(this);`

The original constructs a new `Iterator` object with `this` being passed in as an input parameter to its constructor. But your replacement does not even construct an `Iterator` object at all.

The correct equivalent statement is:

`return std::unique_ptr<Iterator<T, Container>>(new Iterator<T, Container>(this));`

Or better:

`return std::make_unique<Iterator<T, Container>>(this);`